# Building a Live Auction component

Tags: php

I am looking to integrate a live auction component (similar to BigDeal.com) to a website.  I generally program using PHP.  What is the best plan of action with this type of project (Timer, live bids..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a friend who built one.  He said reverse-ajax technology really helped some hurdles. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) is an example of one such implementation.  That way the server can update  browsers when a bid is made.

Comment: +1 for Comet. It ain't easy being white, it ain't easy being brown - All this pressure to be bright, I got children all over town.

Comment: Can your friend suggest any tutorials or educational information on building such a website?